# How should I repair a new crack in the ceiling drywall?

Tags: drywall, crack

Last night there was a huge, house-rattling windstorm. This morning, there's a new hairline crack in some ceiling drywall. What's the best way to repair it? Should I fill the crack with spackle first, or can I just paint it straight away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a paintable latex caulk. Apply a very small amount then work it into the length of the crack with a finger. Wipe off all excess with a damp rag or sponge, then paint. It is a good method requiring no sanding. If your ceiling is painted with flat (no gloss) paint, as most are, you will not be able to see it when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The only correct way to fix it, IMHO, is to get some paper drywall tape, and embed it in some setting-type (the powdered kind that you mix with water yourself) compound.  Do not use the pre-mixed, and do not use fiberglass drywall tape.  In my experience, any other method will eventually open-up on you.

Comment: I don't think this is going to be an easy option, as it's got a popcorn ceiling.

Comment: Yeah, never mind.  Didn't know.  How old is the popcorn?  Up until the late 70's they used to use some asbestos in there. Just wanted to make sure that you were aware.

Comment: 1972. I haven't had it tested, but I'm definitely aware of the possibility of asbestos. It's been painted over a zillion times, but I'm not interested in disturbing any of the popcorn itself.

Answer (score 0):

Stress Crack Tape, a new product out, self adhesive. There is also Goodbye Cracks Elastic Crack Cover Spray. Do a search, these look promising. Even the ones I re paper taped still crack with the ground shifts. I am going to try the above this time. The reviews are good.